# Is there a way to get information about a server using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, windows-server

Is there a way to get information about a server using SQL? It is an Oracle database using a windows server. I searched google and all I found was `@@version` which does not work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What *specific* information about the server do you want to obtain?

Comment: Please, be more specific (about server and DB version too). What are you looking for? Do you need Windows Server name? Windows Server runnig time? Whatever?

Comment: Database version is oracle 11.2.0.1.0 and it is on a windows 03 server with the operating system NT.  I need to get the model number of the server with a SQL statement.  Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Here is a good list of the main informations retrieve routines. Be sure this is the best way to obtain Server infos:

**Oracle**

*Version*: PL/SQL, TNS versions using with Oracle.

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
-- Which version of oracle you are running.
SELECT * FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';
-- Or, in more readable way.
SELECT * FROM product_component_version;
```

*Instance*: Displays the state of the current instance.

```
SELECT * FROM v$instance;
-- About license limits of the current instance.
SELECT * FROM v$license;
```

*Database*: Db Name.

```
SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_NAME
--Db IP Address.
SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_address FROM dual
--Db Host Name.
SELECT UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_NAME('above ip address') FROM dual
```

*Client*: Client IP Address.

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS') FROM dual
--Db Host Name
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL') FROM dual
--Db Host Name with domain.
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','HOST') FROM dual
--Current Client session details who using DB.
SELECT * FROM v$session WHERE username = 'User/Schema name'
--To which DB user connected to.
SELECT SUBSTR(GLOBAL_NAME, 1, INSTR(GLOBAL_NAME,'.')-1) FROM GLOBAL_NAME
```

**SQL Server**

*Version*: Which versions of Sql sever you are running.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
-- SERVERPROPERTY Returns property information about the server instance.
```

*Client*: Client details (IP Address, Machine Name, Instance using).

```
SELECT con.client_net_address as IPAddress,
         sess.host_name as MachineName, sess.program_name as ApplicationName,
         login_name as LoginName
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections con
inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions sess
on con.session_ID=sess.session_ID
WHERE con.session_ID = @@SPID
```

For more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Comment: Great Info.  Thank you so much. It is oracle and is there a way to get the model number of the server using SQL.

Comment: Did you see at linked library in my answer? There are several ways to retrieve infos with SERVERPROPERTY. What do you mean for model number?

Comment: I have servers with AIX as their operating systems and there model numbers are IBM, 9110-510.  I just need the same thing for the windows 03 server.  I have access to the AIX servers and got the model numbers off of them but I cannot log into the windows servers to get it, so I am trying to run an sql statement to find it.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why you are doing this since there are several better ways to get more info of your database, nevertheless:

Try this:

```
select * from v$version;
```

If it returns result, it is **Oracle**.

If not try this:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

If it returns result it is **SQL Server**.

Comment: It is oracle but I tried v$version and it just gives me info on the oracle edition installed.  I think I was able to get what I needed by running select dbms_utility.port_string from dual;  Thanks for your help!