# Oracle system information query - Database instance level

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

I am writing a performance/system monitoring tool to augment load testing for my team's product and I am trying to store database system information with the results bundle but do not know how to write the query to capture this in Oracle (I'm a developer not a DBA).

I have this all working the way I want for SQL Server, but I need to do the same for Oracle.  Below is a query I found online for this is SQL Server:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')) AS 'computerNamePhysicalNetBIOS', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')) AS 'machineName', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')) AS 'edition', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')) AS 'productLevel', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')) AS 'productVersion', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('BuildClrVersion')) AS 'buildClrVersion', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('ProcessID')) AS 'processID', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('EngineEdition')) AS 'engineEdition', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')) AS 'hadrManagerStatus', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled')) AS 'hadrEnabled', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('IsAdvancedAnalyticsInstalled')) AS 'advancedAnalyticsInstalled', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')) AS 'clustered', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('IsPolybaseInstalled')) AS 'polybaseInstalled', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('IsXTPSupported')) AS 'xtpSupported', 
CONVERT(INT,SERVERPROPERTY('LCID')) AS 'lcid', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ResourceVersion')) AS 'resourceVersion', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')) AS 'serverName', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),APP_NAME() )AS 'appName', 
CONVERT(INT,DB_ID()) AS 'dbId', 
CONVERT(varchar(128),DB_NAME()) AS 'dbName'
```

I don't really expect a one-to-one column match between the above query and Oracle's version, but in general, how can I get very similar information from Oracle?

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16566142/266304) for some of the equivalent information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't really expect a one-to-one column match between the above
>   query and Oracle's version, but in general, how can I get very similar
>   information from Oracle?

Most of that stuff, if it exists at all in the Oracle database, will be accessible through V$ views in the Oracle database.  To get you started, here are some that are going to be most relevant to answering your question:

```
select * from v$instance;

select * from v$version;

select * from v$sql_feature;

select * from v$license;

select * from v$option;
```

If you want to get a complete list of V$ views to look around better,

```
select * from dict where table_name like 'V$%';
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

Some of those things are specific to MSSQL and have no meaning in Oracle. But you can get many of them with [`sys_context()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117) using the `userenv` namespace.

For instance, to get the database name:

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'DB_NAME') as db_name
from dual;
```